# Substring go to End of String

Tags: c#

I am trying to get have one Substring go from the beginning of a string to a certain position and another Substring go from the end of the last position to the end of the string. But I don't know what the end will be. it will be multiple lengths. Is there a way to just go to the end of the string without giving a specific character position, something like below?

```
StartVariable.Substring(0, 14)
EndVariable.Substring(15, Substring.Length)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what you're after - before/after?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use `EndVariable.Substring(15)`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
string start = input.Remove(15);
string end = input.Substring(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like:

```
EndVariable.Substring(14);
```

Comment: Providing the `Length` isn't really necessary when you want the rest of the string. It's simpler to do `Substring(14)`.